# How to iterate over a list of objects that do not have an id property

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, codable

These are examples of two models that I have that are populated from network calls.

```
struct CombinedValueModel : Codable{

    let identifiers: [ValueModel]

    let descriptors: [ValueModel]

    let amount: Double
}

struct ValueModel : Codable, Identifiable{

    let id: String

    let name: String?

    let value: String

}
```

I am trying to use them in a list but the `CombinedValueModel` does not conform to `Identifiable`. Model contains a list of `CombinedValueModels`.

```
List(Model.values){ value in
    Text("$\(value.amount, specifier: "%.2f")")
}
```

How do I make it possible to iterate over the values?

I have tried giving the id: \.self to the List but that makes it so that the `CombinedValueModel` has to conform to `Hashable` and that leads to implementing your own "==" func. That leads to making ValueModel conform to `Equatable` and `Hashable`.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conform to `Identifiable` protocol using an `id` property, that you exclude from your `CodingKeys`. Manually generate a unique identifier for each instance of your struct using `UUID`,  like this:

```
struct CombinedValueModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let identifiers: [ValueModel]
    let descriptors: [ValueModel]
    let amount: Double
    let id = UUID().uuidString

    // Need to add CodingKeys enum to exclude id from being decoded
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case identifiers
        case descriptors
        case amount
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: Side note. If you want it to actually generate a value on id then you must add `UUID().uuidString` to the struct instead of just `UUID()`